# Can NumberFormatInfo use significant digits?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, number-formatting

I'm using System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo to format my numbers in my C#.NET WinRT app, and things are working as expected, with one exception.

That is, **I need a way to have the formatter honor the significant digits of the number I'm formatting**.

In Objective C, I use NSNumberFormatter.UsesSignificantDigits, described here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/usesSignificantDigits

However, NumberFormatInfo doesn't seem to have anything corresponding to this functionality.  The `NumberDecimalDigits` property seems to take a single number, which is applied without regard for the number being formatted (which is what I want all the time I'm *not* trying to format while honoring significant digits)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.105).aspx

Can I use NumberFormatInfo to solve this problem, or do I have to use something other than NumberFormatInfo to format my numbers?  And if I need to do something else, what's the best approach?

For example, I'd like the following numbers to be formatted in the following ways:

- 2.5 -> 2.5
- 3 -> 3
- 4.3333333 -> 4.3333333
- 3.66666 -> 3.66666

*rather than the following*

- 2.5 -> 2.50
- 3 -> 3.00
- 4.3333333 -> 4.33
- 3.66666 -> 3.67

Comment: For that you don't have to use `NumberFormatInfo` just call `ToString()`.

Comment: Oh, interesting point.  I'll give that a shot, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with just using `.ToString()`, but I want to make sure my decimal separator, grouping separator, and so on are all used properly, so I ended up implementing it this way, and I'm pretty happy with the results.

`value` is the `double` I'm trying to format.

```
CultureInfo culture = this.CurrentCulture;
string decimalSeparator = culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
string temp = value.ToString();
string[] splitter = temp.Split(decimalSeparator[0]);
int numDigitsToDisplay = 0;
if( splitter.Length > 1)
{
    numDigitsToDisplay = splitter[1].Length;
}
numDigitsToDisplay = Math.Min(10, numDigitsToDisplay); // Make sure no more than 10 digits are displayed after the decimal point
NumberFormatInfo tempNFI = (NumberFormatInfo)culture.NumberFormat.Clone();
tempNFI.NumberDecimalDigits = numDigitsToDisplay;
double roundedValue = Math.Round((double)value, numDigitsToDisplay, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // just in case the number's after-decimal digits exceed the maximum I ever want to display (10)
return roundedValue.ToString("N", tempNFI);
```